# How can I find out how jQuery serializes individual objects?

Tags: jquery, arrays, jquery-plugins, each

I have this HTML and JS code:

```
<form id="myForm">
<input type="text" name="option_a[]">
<input type="text" name="option_a[]">
<input type="text" name="option_a[]">
</form>

<script>
var data_form = $('#myForm').serializeArray();  
jQuery.each(data_form, function( i, val ) {
    console.log(i+" "+val);
});
</script>
```

The console output should look like this:

```
option_a[]=1
option_a[]=2
option_a[]=3
```

but now it's showing me:

```
object object
object object
object object
```

Comment: thanks my problem solved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run:

```
console.log(i+" "+val);
```

the values of `i` and `val` will be converted to strings (by calling `.toString()` on them).  Often, for complex objects, the resulting output won't be particularly helpful.

Instead, you can pass multiple arguments to [`console.log()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log) directly, e.g. as in:

```
console.log(i, ":", val);
```

This lets the console display the arguments in a more useful manner; many implementations will even let you click on the output to expand and inspect it in more detail.

Comment: No problem. If this answer solved your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the check mark icon on the left. Once you've collected [a few more rep points](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up), you can also vote up any posts that you find helpful.

Answer (score -1):

After run your i is index and val is value so you can put together using console

```
data_form[0]
```

Comment: console.log(i, ":", val);